# Using Scanner to find values inside string

Tags: android, android-fragments, java.util.scanner

I wrote a Scanner that goes looking for [integers or Folats] inside a string, however, I want to evaluate the string to find the number of likes inside it. and get the times only and not any number.

String for example:

"User liked 80.00 images this month on the account 15478 until this date 02/10/2019"

```
            try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner( message ).useDelimiter( "[^\\d.]+" );
            VlauesInMessage = scanner.nextInt();
            Log.w("Enter IntSCanner", String.valueOf( VlauesInMessage ));
            scanner.close();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
              System.out.print(e.getMessage()); 
            }
```

however,

I want the scanner to stop after a certain word appears such as "Images" because sometimes it brings me 15478 or 10 as result. 
is There any better idea to extract the liked times keep in mind sometimes the number of likes can be 80.10.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you want. Do you want all the numbers in the `String` before the word "images"?

Comment: No my wish is the number before the word images. For example if a number occurs then the word images accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has method `findWithinHorizon(String,int)`. Find the location of the word "images" in the input and use that as your limit when calling method `findWithinHorizon()`. Here is a simple example.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(message);
String str = s.findWithinHorizon("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", message.indexOf("images"));
```

The result, using your sample input is:

80.00

There is also method `skip(String)`. So in order to scan for a number after the word "images", use the following:

```
s.skip("^.*images")
String str = s.findWithinHorizon("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", 0);
```

For your sample input the result is:

15478

Comment: that's a nice method I didn't know about it before, Thank you.